# Creating an instance of Room Database inside the callback or use the member variable of that database

Tags: java, android, callback, android-room

What is the difference between creating an object of RoomDatabase to use inside the callback like what is in this example of [BasicSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/db/AppDatabase.java) at line 83, and 88,

And,

Using the member variable of RoomDatabase inside the callback like what is in this example of [android-room-with-a-view](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordRoomDatabase.java) at line 71?

I am not asking for opinion, I am asking if there is a difference or benefits  between the two examples?

I don't know why there is no answer

Answer (score 0):

**IN SHORT**

**In short, both the code are pretty same. They check the value of a member variable. If the value already exists, simply return that value without creating new object. Else if, the value of variable is null, in that case create a new object, assign the object to member variable and then return the value.**

**IN LONG**

Both the code that you have mentioned are just to implement the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). There are multiple ways to achieve this:

> android-architecture-components repository

```
AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(appContext, executors);
```

In the above code, we are calling the `getInstance(.. , ..)` method, which  implements the singleton pattern in following ways:

```
public static AppDatabase getInstance(final Context context, final AppExecutors executors) {
if (sInstance == null) {
    synchronized (AppDatabase.class) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = buildDatabase(context.getApplicationContext(), executors);
            sInstance.updateDatabaseCreated(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
}
   return sInstance;
}
```

The `getInstance()` method **not always creates new Object**. Instead, it checks for the value of member variable `sInstance`. If the value is `null` assign it the value of DB object and then return the value. And in case the value is not null, simply return the value already stored i.e value of previous DB object.

> android-room-with-a-view repository

It also does the pretty same thing, i.e using the same singleton value `INSTANCE`
and passing it to **new object of AsyncTask**.

`new PopulateDbAsync(INSTANCE).execute();`

**Singleton pattern**

```
static WordRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (WordRoomDatabase.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        WordRoomDatabase.class, "word_database")
                        // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating if no Migration object.
                        // Migration is not part of this codelab.
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

Comment: first: there is conflict in your answer because you said both of them are implementing  [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and then you said the function `AppDatabase.getInstance(appContext, executors);` doesn't implement [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: second: both of them are creating or initializing the member variable if this member variable is null, but the difference is in the callback 
in the callback of both of them they are creating already stored data inside the software, 
but in the example of BasicSample the line 83 is not needed and the member variable can be passed instead the variable database at line 88 and used to call the function `.setDatabaseCreated();` because -and here I am asking- the callback will be called or executed directly after `.build();`?

Comment: hello @ankuranurag2

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to say in second comment.

Comment: both of them are inserting data by the callback but in [android-room-with-a-view](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordRoomDatabase.java) `INSTANCE` is used and in [BasicSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/db/AppDatabase.java) a variable `database` is used which is created at line 83 why `sInstance` is not used?

Comment: hello @ankuranurag2

Comment: The `getInstance()` method in `AppDatabase.getInstance(appContext, executors);` is ultimately returning `sInstance` only.

Comment: The `getInstance()` methods returns `sInstance` which is an instance of Database. Then we perform DB actions on this instance. Go to line 64 in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/db/AppDatabase.java

Comment: The variable `database` at line 83 is holding the value of `sInstance` which is returned from `getInstance()` method at line 64.

Comment: Do you want to say that if `sInstance` is used or the variable `database` both are the same ?

Comment: hello @ankuranurag2

Comment: Yes, the variables `database` and `sInstance` are both of same type i.e `AppDataBase`. Also, no need to say hello after every comment. I get notifications, so i am aware that you have added new comment.

Comment: But `sInstance` should not be used directly. It might be possible that it is not initalized/NULL when you use it. But when you use `database`, it gets its value from `getInstance()` which ensure that the value is intialized/not null. So using the value returned from `getInstance()`  i.e. `database` is preferred.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, then you can accept/upvote it so that it might help others in future.

Comment: But in [android-room-with-a-view](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordRoomDatabase.java) `INSTANCE` is used because I read -that what I asked in the second comment- that the callback will be called or executed directly after `.build();`?

Comment: I want to say `INSTANCE` is used in [android-room-with-a-view](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordRoomDatabase.java) because the callback will be called or executed directly after `.build();`?

Comment: ... because the callback will be called or executed directly after `.build();`? if that is the reason then there is no problem?

Comment: Whenever a person will call the `getDatabase()` method from anywhere, callback to `onOpen()` would arrive and the statements inside it would be executed.

Comment: Also if you go through the comments above the callback method, it states:


      `Override the onOpen method to populate the database.
      For this sample, we clear the database every time it is created or opened.
     
      If you want to populate the database only when the database is created for the 1st time,
      override RoomDatabase.Callback()#onCreate`

Comment: Callback would be executed directly.

Comment: Yes I want to say, when `INSTANCE` is used in [android-room-with-a-view](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordRoomDatabase.java) because the callback will be called or executed directly after `.build();`, `sInstance` also can be used in [BasicSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/db/AppDatabase.java) in the same way without any problem

Comment: Yes it can be used.

Comment: As a Conclusion, the short answer will be `sInstance` can be used in place of the variable `database` and we don't know why they created and used the variable `database` in [BasicSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/db/AppDatabase.java)